# Remove/Hide Bearer authentication Swashbuckle and Swagger on an ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle and Swagger on an ASP.NET Web API with bearer authentication.

Is it possible to remove this authentication for a specific web api method or controller?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? `[AllowAnonymous]`?

Comment: In this specific controller (for exemple) it is not necessary use bearer autentication to access all methods. No authentication for this controller

Comment: Can you share some code? `[AllowAnonymous]` should work ...